# Break a div into two parts and display half below a fixed div and half above

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a fixed div halfway down the page.  I have another div that contains a gallery of images.  Currently the images scroll 'undearneath' the fixed div as expected.  But I'm going for an effect where the images are never hidden beneath the fixed div.  Instead of going undereath the div, they'd be split up, with part of the image displaying below and part above.  Essentially I'm looking to break one div (the one with the gallery of images) into two parts, with part displaying below the fixed div and part above.  Here's some fancy graphics to better illustrate what I'm hoping to do.

I'm happy to use any combination of css/html/javascript that is required.

Is it possible?

```
  Current Behavior           Desired Behavior
|===================|     |===================|
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |     |  |     |  |
| | img |  | img |  |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |  1  |  |  2  |  |     | |  1  |  |  2  |  |
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
|===================|     |===================|
|   fixed   div     |     |   fixed   div     |
|===================|     |===================|
| |  3  |  |  4  |  |     |  =====    =====   |
|  =====    =====   |     | |     |  |     |  |
|  =====    =====   |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |  3  |  |  4  |  |
| | img |  | img |  |     |  =====    =====   |
|===================|     |===================|
```

scroll a bit

```
|===================|     |===================|
| | img |  | img |  |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |  1  |  |  2  |  |     | |  1  |  |  2  |  |
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |     |  |     |  |
|===================|     |===================|
|   fixed   div     |     |   fixed   div     |
|===================|     |===================|
|  =====    =====   |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |  3  |  |  4  |  |
| | img |  | img |  |     |  =====    =====   |
| |  5  |  |  6  |  |     |  =====    =====   |
|  =====    =====   |     | |     |  |     |  |
|===================|     |===================|
```

scroll a bit more

```
|===================|     |===================|
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
|  =====    =====   |     |  =====    =====   |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |     |  |     |  |
| | img |  | img |  |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |  3  |  |  4  |  |     | |  3  |  |  4  |  |
|===================|     |===================|
|   fixed   div     |     |   fixed   div     |
|===================|     |===================|
| | img |  | img |  |     |  =====    =====   |
| |  5  |  |  6  |  |     |  =====    =====   |
|  =====    =====   |     | |     |  |     |  | 
|  =====    =====   |     | | img |  | img |  |
| |     |  |     |  |     | |  5  |  |  6  |  |
|===================|     |===================|
```

Comment: +1 for the "fancy graphics"

Comment: I can't do it for you at the moment, but my approach would be to have 3 `overflow-y:scroll` divs (top area, fixed area, and bottom area - this also allows for an easy no-js fallback if you want), put your scrolling HTML in the top div, duplicate it with Javascript into the bottom div, and simply calculate top&bottom's top position based on the page's scroll position.

Comment: What if you use the div like the social bar divs that are present on various websites. They get "stuck" to a fixed location on the screen, but this will cover your content though.
Div class: 
`.something{
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: some px;
 width: some px;
}` It should be put right where the body tag starts and not included inside any other div.

Answer (score 6):

Here I quickly put together a combination of html, css and jquery, that worked for me in Chrome.

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CsAB8/)**

**html:**

```
    <div id="toppart">
        <div class="tiles">
            <div class="tile">1</div>
            <div class="tile">2</div>
            <div class="tile">3</div>
            <div class="tile">4</div>
            <div class="tile">5</div>
            <div class="tile">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="strap">
        <p>the fixed strap</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottompart"></div>
```

crucial part of **css:**

```
#strap {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#toppart, #bottompart {
    background-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    height:45%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#bottompart {
    top:55%;
    z-index:-1;
}

#bottompart div {
    position:relative;
    top:-100%;
}
```

and the **javascript** code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          //mirror contents
          $('#bottompart').append($('#toppart').html());
          //scroll bottom with top
          $("#toppart").scroll(function(){
                 $("#bottompart").scrollTop($("#toppart").scrollTop());
          });
          //scroll top with bottom
          $("#bottompart").scroll(function(){
                 $("#toppart").scrollTop($("#bottompart").scrollTop());
          });
    });
```

Hope you get the idea ;-)

Comment: That's pretty cool. I hope nobody uses it in production though; it's an accessibility nightmare, not to mention doubling-up IDs.

Comment: @Dave i just threw it together quickly for the general idea ... and I agree, especially the CSS would require some work and adjustment for the final appearance. However, I understood SO as a way of sharing ideas and helping people solve their problems ... and not necessarily produce off-the-shelf products. But what you mean with doubling-up ids?

Comment: This is just for a fun side project so I'm not actually all that worried about accessibility.  It works great in chrome and firefox, but it's really jumpy in Safari.  Any idea why that might be?  If I can figure out how to fix that, it'd be good enough for my needs. It's definitely cool, btw :)

Comment: @MartinTurjak yeah I'm just noting it in case somebody comes along and thinks: "ooh! copy/paste!". For doubling up IDs, I mean if the content had `<div id="blah">`, then you would end up with 2 divs with id blah. Which is technically forbidden.

Comment: @Dave I see, well this is why I used classes on most contents and ids really only for the elements that appear only once, but you could also do this with different elements and selectors and avoid even the classes altogether.

Comment: @KrisF, for me it works smoothly in Safari 6.0.3, Firefox and Chrome, only in Opera it is a bit off, but not too bad. I dont know. I tried a different synchronization script that I now googled somewhere http://jsfiddle.net/CsAB8/1/, maybe this works better for you. Here I put just text into the divs http://jsfiddle.net/CsAB8/2/ if maybe the floated tiles did not play right, and it in all cases scrolls smoothly for me ... this is all I can think of now. But there is a lot of stuff online on jerky scrolling issues ... hope you can find something that solves the problem in your browser.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Hmm, I'm on Safari 6.0.3 as well.  It's smooth if you scroll real slow, but otherwise it's jumpy.  I've been researching but I haven't found anything yet to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with CSS. The only viable implementation I see is to have a top and bottom div with exactly the same content, listen to their onscroll events, and then 'sync' them to the other with the required gap. You would need some degradation for iOS devices though because they don't send onscroll events until scroll is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to tackle this, but it uses JavaScript.

I use JavaScript to duplicate the original content and split into two sections. (that way you don't have to serve twice the content)

The top section has a higher z-index than the bottom, overflow is hidden, and position is fixed.  The height is set to the distance from the top of the page to the middle element.  Its content is moved into a wrapper div within this section, allowing it to act like a viewport.

The bottom section is aligned with the top section, but has a padding at the top equal to the middle section (pushing the content down by that amount).  The top section covers up the content for the top half, so you only see the part below the middle element (highest z-index).

One problem with this is that it requires the top section to have a background, which needs to match the background of the page.

I've put together a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/mwkM8/

HTML:

```
<div id='content'>
    <p>Your Content Here</p>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/250/' alt='img' />
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/250/' alt='img' />
</div>
<div id='middle'></div>
```

JS:

```
(function(w,d){
    var top = d.getElementById('content'),
        bottom = top.cloneNode(true),
        middle = d.getElementById('middle'),
        top_content = d.createElement('div');

    top.id = 'top';
    bottom.id = 'bottom';
    top_content.id = 'top_content';


    top_content.innerHTML = top.innerHTML;
    top.innerHTML = '';


    top.style.display = 'none'; //more efficient to change the style while the element is not displayed, and then display

    top.style.height = middle.offsetTop + 'px';

    bottom.style.paddingTop = middle.scrollHeight + 'px';
    console.log(middle.scrollHeight);

    top.parentNode.appendChild(bottom);
    top.appendChild(top_content);
    top.style.display = bottom.style.display = 'block';

    w.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        var y = (w.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? w.pageYOffset : (d.documentElement || d.body.parentNode || d.body).scrollTop;
        top_content.style.top = -y + 'px';
    }, false);
})(window, document);
```

CSS:

```
#middle{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top:-25px;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}

#top,#bottom{
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
}

#top{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:50;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#top_content{
    position:relative;
}

#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:25;
}
```

Comment: Very cool.  Nice and smooth too on the browsers I tested.  Any idea why it doesn't scroll on the iPad/iPhone though?

Comment: As I understand it, the ios devices don't fire their 'onscroll' event until after the scroll is finished. That might be the issue, but I didn't really look too deep into it.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot that `position:fixed` isn't really supported, which is more likely the cause of your problems.  See http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed for reference